# Find out most popular from different results

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

This is more of a mathematical question than a programming question, but it still includes some programming.

This program scrapes the information from user lists on the IMDB website, and is supposed to display the most popular celebrity of all of the inputted lists. This works, just displays inaccurate results.

This is what I have:

```
            public List<Star[]> stars = new List<Star[]>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Processing...";
        stars.Add(ParseList(textBox1.Text));

        label1.Text = "Waiting.";

        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        List<Star> strs = new List<Star>();

        foreach (Star[] stlst in stars)
        {
            foreach (Star s in stlst)
            {
                bool inalrdy = false;

                int index = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < strs.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (s.Name == strs[i].Name)
                    {
                        inalrdy = true;
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (inalrdy)
                {
                    strs[index].Points += s.Points;
                }
                else
                {
                    strs.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (Star s in strs)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(s.Points + ". " + s.Name);
        }


    }
```

What would I do to have it rank them accurately even when there is never the same players?

This is very important to me and I would be very grateful for an answer.

Comment: In this example, where do you declare the variable s?

Comment: so what you want is some kind of system that tracks who has beaten/loss against every other player. i'm assuming that if a beats b then b cannot beat a in another result.

Comment: s was supposed to be p, accidentally changed it.

Comment: This is supposed to use rank data from all games and create an accurate leaderboard.

Comment: if plrs is List<Player> then you should have foreach (Player p in plrs) and not  foreach (Player[] pllst in plrs)

Comment: plrs is a list of arrays of the Player class, each array is for all of the players in one game, and the list contains all of the games.

Comment: **foreach (Player[] pllst in plrs)** seems incorrect. I assume that you have a list containing lists of players, but then it should be **foreach (Player[] pllst in SOMEOTHERLIST)**

Comment: public List<Player[]> plrs = new List<Player[]>();          This is a list for all of the games, and a game is represented by an array of the players who played in it.

Comment: Please make sure you code compiles, this is not working.

Comment: It compiles, and it works. But it only works in a way that is only accurate if all of the same players where in all of the games, but that is not the case.

Comment: The first 2 lines of the code you have provided will cause an compile error...

Comment: Ok, fine. I changed what this what about because I was paranoid that someone would steal my idea. So I edited the code in the browser and made some errors, I will post the actual code in a minute.

Comment: OK, so you wish to create a DISTINCT list of all items, with their Points added together. Then the List should be sorted by the total points desc? Is that what you are after?

Comment: That is what I have, but not what I want. Say in one list Meagan Fox is ranked 11, and 20 in another, then Will Ferral is ranked 23 in another, if you do it how I have it, Will would be ranked as more liked when he really isn't.

Comment: So do you determine the *best* rank as the lowest, or highest? Or do you wish to have an average?

Comment: It is like "Meagan Fox is my #1 favorite star" "Will Farrel is my 2nd favorite star", and I just thought that averages might be the solution, so I asked to verify.

Comment: So then average would seem to be the more appropriate choice, me thinks.

Comment: Ok, but what code would I use for that? I would have to average them all at once to get the correct answer. I can't use code similar to what I have, because if you average two results, then average that answer with a different result it won't be correct. I am sure I can work it out, but it would be awesome for someone to post an easy way to do that.

Comment: I have provided some sample code to do this using LINQ

Comment: Wait, only using averages still won't result in an accurate answer. if someone is number one in one list, but isn't even in all of the others, they will still  be looked at as number one.

Answer (score 0):

You have the relationship of players for each list, but what you want is the relationship of players overall.
Assuming that this is solvable (i.e there is information to rank each player and there is no cases where player 1 and 2 has beaten each other)

The algorithm would look something like:

1. Get the first ranking player in the first list. Traverse through the first element of each remaining list to see if that player is beaten. If yes, replace by the player that beats him, otherwise he's number one.
2. Remove that player from the list.
3. Repeat from 1.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so how about some [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746)?

Something like

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name;
    public double Rank;
}

List<List<Player>> someOtherList = new List<List<Player>>
                                   {
                                       new List<Player> 
                                           {
                                               new Player {Name = "A", Rank = 1}, 
                                               new Player {Name = "B", Rank = 2}
                                           },
                                       new List<Player>
                                           {
                                               new Player {Name = "A", Rank = 2}, 
                                               new Player {Name = "C", Rank = 1}
                                           }
                                   };

List<Player> plrs = 
        (from p in someOtherList.SelectMany(singleList => singleList)
        group p by p.Name into g
         select new Player { Name = g.Key, Rank = g.Average(x => x.Rank) })
         .OrderBy(x => x.Rank)
         .ToList();

foreach (Player p in plrs)
{
    OverallPlayers.Add(p.Rank + ". " + p.Name);
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed to look something like the OP code. I would dtill strongly recomend you spend some time on that LINQ tutorial once you feel better...

```
List<Star[]> stars = new List<Star[]>
                                       {
                                           new[]
                                               {
                                                   new Star {Name = "A", Points = 1}, 
                                                   new Star {Name = "B", Points = 2}
                                               },
                                           new[]
                                               {
                                                   new Star {Name = "A", Points = 2}, 
                                                   new Star {Name = "C", Points = 1}
                                               }
                                       };
List<Star> plrs =
        (from p in stars.SelectMany(singleList => singleList)
        group p by p.Name into g
         select new Star { Name = g.Key, Points = g.Average(x => x.Points) })
         .OrderBy(x => x.Points)
         .ToList();

foreach (Star p in plrs)
{
    //OverallPlayers.Add(p.Rank + ". " + p.Name);
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand that. Can you please edit it so that I could just copy and paste to my code (Which is exactly the same as my updated post). I am sick, and can't really think strait, so I would be very gracious.

Comment: Wait, only using averages still won't result in an accurate answer. if someone is number one in one list, but isn't even in all of the others, they will still be looked at as number one.

Comment: That is unfortunately what averages will give you. The other way I can see this work is that you assign some sort of weight/number to each position, and then count these up. I assum that your list run from 1 downwards, so just adding these 'Ranks' will also not produce the desired result. You will have to assign points to a given position, much like they do in F1 races. So even if a person only partisipated oince, and came first, they will not win the cup. You see where im goin with this?

Comment: Ok, I will see what I can do.